# Is b a linear combination of a1, a2, and a3?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Question:

Given $a_1, a_2, a_3,$ and $b$ below, determine if $b$ is a linear combination of $a_1, a_2,$ and $a_3$.

$a_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
-2\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$
$a_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0\\
5
\end{bmatrix}
$
$a_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
5\\
-6\\
8
\end{bmatrix}
$

$b = \begin{bmatrix}
2\\
-1\\
6
\end{bmatrix}
$

I create an augmented matrix from the above, and after reducing I get the following matrix.

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 5 & 2\\
0 & 1 & 4 & 3\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$

Thus I conclude that b is a linear combination of $a_1, a_2,$ and $a_3$. The issue is that the answer to this question in the book is $b$ is **not** a linear combination of $a_1, a_2$, and $a_3$.

Can someone tell me why this is so? It seems like my answer should be correct.

Comment: Please check ur reduced system...i think it is not vorrect

Comment: There was an error in my question, I have fixed it. The reduced system is correct, but b was incorrect.

Comment: Note that $b=2a_1+3a_2.$ So there is a typo in the book.

Comment: how is that a typo? I don't understand? So am I right in this case?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly a linear combination as 2 times first column and 3 times second  column and 0 times third column equal b.

Probably it was a typo in your book.